# Processing a method synchronously in Node.js

Tags: node.js, async.js

I've inherited some Node.js code and I need to add some functionality. However, I'm not sure syntactically how to accomplish my goal due to the asynchronous nature of Node. Currently, I have a function defined like this:

```
return {
  myEntryPoint: function(req, res) {
    var results = getResults();
    res.send(200, results);
  }
};
```

Several pieces are calling this function already. Inside of it, I'm calling a function called getResults which is defined like this:

```
var getResults = function() {
  var results = [];
  async.series([
    function(callback) {
      // add to results
    },

    function(callback) {
      // add to results
    }
  ]);

  return results;
};
```

My problem is, I need to wait until all of the functions inside of the async.series call are made before I return the results. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change it to add a callback. [Series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) has an optional callback to run once all the functions have completed within.

```
var getResults = function(finished) {
    var results = [];
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            // add to results
        },

        function(callback) {
            // add to results
        }
    ], function() {
        //Called when series is finished
        finished(results);
    });
};
```

And to get the results,

```
return {
    myEntryPoint: function(req, res) {
        getResults(function(results) {
            res.send(200, results);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this is to take a callback that uses the argument in question.

```
results = getResults(args);
someFunction(results);
```

Is equivalent to

```
function getResults(args, callback) {
    var results;
    //do stuff and populate results.
    callback(results);
}
getResults(args, someFunction);
```

Except you don't have the issue of trying to wait for async stuff to happen, which you can't do, without weird logic.